# Django: how to refresh or reload models from database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Some of my tables in database are periodicity updated by several python scripts outside of Django. As a result, the Django's views are not aware of the latest data in database and is showing the old data. I have tried many suggestions online but nothing work except called connection.close() before using the model.

**Here are the approaches I have tried, nothing worked.**

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache # <=====
def GetData(request):
    data = Table.objects.get(id=1) # Still giving outdated data

    template = loader.get_template('data/data.html')
    context = Context({
        'lp': lp,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

---

```
data = Data.objects.get(id=1)
data = data.objects.get(id=data.id) # data is still old
```

---

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.clear()
```

**The approach that works.**:

```
from django.db import connection
def GetData(request):
    # Add this before accessing the model.
    # This also connection.close() prevents the 
    # MySQL 2006, 'MySQL server has gone away' error.
    connection.close()

    data = Table.objects.get(id=1) # Giving outdated data

    template = loader.get_template('data/data.html')
    context = Context({
        'lp': lp,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: Here is a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED" to my.cnf. More details here: [How do I force Django to ignore any caches and reload data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data)