# Caching in Djangos object model

Tags: django

I'm running a system with a few workers that's taking jobs from a message queue, all using Djangos ORM.
In one case I'm actually passing a message along from one worker to another in another queue.
It works like this:

- Worker1 in queue1 creates an object (MySQL INSERT) and pushes a message to queue2
- Worker2 accepts the new message in queue2 and retrieves the object (MySQL SELECT), using Djangos objects.get(pk=object_id)

This works for the first message. But in the second message worker 2 always fails on that it can't find object with id object_id (with Django exception DoesNotExist).

This works seamlessly in my local setup with Django 1.2.3 and MySQL 5.1.66, the problem occurs  only in my test environment which runs Django 1.3.1 and MySQL 5.5.29.

If I restart worker2 every time before worker1 pushes a message, it works fine. This makes me believe there's some kind of caching going on.

Is there any caching involved in Django's objects.get() that differs between these versions? If that's the case, can I clear it in some way?

Comment: Are you making sure that you commit the transaction **before** adding the second task? Maybe you just have one worker in the local setup and multiple workers in production.

Comment: Also, ensure that the MySQL transaction setup is correct for the Django end.  Some people seem to have problems relating to read transaction isolation.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3346124/302243

Comment: Thanks guys! You we're correct, I need to manually make sure the transaction is committed before submitting it to the other workers.
@AustinPhillips your link helped a lot, put it in an answer if you would like and I'll give you the credit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely related to the use of MySQL transactions.  On the sender's site, the transaction must be committed to the database before notifying the receiver of an item to read.  On the receiver's side, the transaction level used for a session must be set such that the new data becomes visible in the session after the sender's commit.

By default, MySQL uses the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level.  This poses problems where there are more than one process reading/writing to the database.  One possible solution is to set the isolation level in the Django `settings.py` file using a `DATABASES` option like the following:

```
'OPTIONS': {'init_command': 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED'},
```

Note however that changing the transaction isolation level may have other side effects, especially when using statement based replication.

The following links provide more useful information:

- [How do I force Django to ignore any caches and reload data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data)
- [Django ticket#13906](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13906)