# How to force queryset evaluation in loop?

Tags: python, django, evaluation, django-queryset

Quite simple task: generate 30 xlsx files (one for every day in month) at once and make it downloadable as zip archive. Xlsx files have the same structure, only diference is data.

I thought it will be very easy, something like:

```
for date in dates:
    report_data = ReportModel.objects.filter(date_id = date)
    xlsx = generate_xlsx_file(report_data)
    add_to_zip_archive(xlsx)
```

It's not a real code of course, just to show some idea.
This method not work in Django. I get empty files (not 0kB, but valid Excel files with no data inside).

When I do like this:

```
report_data = ReportModel.objects.filter(date_id = date1)
xlsx = generate_xlsx_file(report_data)
add_to_zip_archive(xlsx)

report_data = ReportModel.objects.filter(date_id = date2)
xlsx = generate_xlsx_file(report_data)
add_to_zip_archive(xlsx)

report_data = ReportModel.objects.filter(date_id = date3)
xlsx = generate_xlsx_file(report_data)
add_to_zip_archive(xlsx)

report_data = ReportModel.objects.filter(date_id = date4)
xlsx = generate_xlsx_file(report_data)
add_to_zip_archive(xlsx)
```

it works. I have 30 files full of data.

Yes, I read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated and I have no idea what is wrong.
Making a list:

```
report_data = list(ReportModel.objects.filter(date_id = date))
```

not help, **`report_data` it is empty every time I use FOR loop.**

So, I really have to write 30 times the same in my code? There are some workarounds, hidden features? If not, it really looks like a big fail.

Comment: Are you sure your queries return any data? Did you try them as plain SQL?

Comment: @9000 Yes, I'm sure. When I remove loop as I described files are generated properly.

Comment: Please show an example of `dates` and `date1` etc.

Comment: `dates` is a list of numbers made from another queryset from database (it works). `date_id` in this case in a number in format `yyyymmdd` for example `20140113`.

Comment: @EWit In my first example `date` is a number in format specified above. It is an element of list `dates`. `date1`,`date2` etc are numbers just like `date`. If I specify `date_id__id=date` I get only one queryset, but I need 30 querysets. I see some workaroud here. I can use only one big queryset with all my dates and manually filter it in Python...

Comment: as @EWit suggests, make sure `for date in dates` is giving you the out put you expect. Print it out before your function calls to double check.

Comment: @EWit I'm not sure what your snippet does. Can you explain? `generate_xlsx_file` expect queryset and this queryset is iterated inside (next for loop) to create rows in excel file (I use XlsxWriter there).
@themanatuf It puts 30 numbers as I expect.

Comment: @nbrc in that case I don't know. Try to log all input/output from methods and maybe you see something which is out of place.

Comment: From what you've described the answer must be that `for date in dates` is not giving you the same values for `date` as you have when you manually type in the dates

Comment: to test, does this work: `report_data = ReportModel.objects.filter(date_id=dates[0])` ?

Comment: I came into this problem and found this post is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data. Add `qs.update()` may solve this problem