# Django get query unwanted cached

Tags: python, django, caching

I am writing some test code using pure python unittest. I did it like this:

```
# retrieve the demo object to get the initial attributes
demo = DemoModel.objects.get(id='1')
init_name = demo.name
# use the requests module to send a request to change attributes of demo
requests.post(...)
# retrieve the demo object again to see if it's changed
demo = DemoModel.objects.get(id='1')
assertNotEqual(init_name, demo.name)
```

Turns out the demo object wasn't changed! I searched and checked for a long time, but, there is no cache in Django `get`query, mysql neither.

Answer (score 0):

You said you did this in "pure unittest" and using the requests module. If you're not careful in doing so, it's quite possible that your request failed -- and you aren't checking the status code of your POST. (One possible reason it could fail would be if you don't provide Django's CSRF value, for example, though it might also fail from a permission check, etc).

Do you know if the post returned successfully?

Comment: Yes I am absolutely sure. The request returned HTTP 200, and I check the database, the column of the row has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems not Django but Mysql transaction issue. See [How do I force Django to ignore any caches and reload data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data)