# python django modelname.objects.all().count() din't return actual size

Tags: python, django

I made a small queue in database, for resend a sort of a content. When I need to get real time statistics for queue length, I've got wrong length (go to database and watch count of rows)

some code to explain: model.py

```
class SentSMS( models.Model ):
     phone = models.ForeignKey( 'Subscriber', verbose_name=u'Абонент' )
     text = models.CharField( max_length=160, verbose_name=u'Сообщение' )
     free = models.BooleanField( default=False, verbose_name=u'Бесплатная смс' )
     sent_date = models.DateTimeField( default=datetime.datetime.now, verbose_name=u'Дата отправки' )
     price = models.FloatField( verbose_name=u'Стоимость СМС' )
     subscription = models.ForeignKey( 'Subscription', verbose_name=u'Подписка', blank=True, null=True )
     priority = models.IntegerField( verbose_name=u'Приоритет', default=0 )
```

There is job, that places messages in queue, or get some data. So, queue length always changes.

when a try to do this (in one session) `SentSMS.objects.all().count()`, it always shows the same length. But, when I restart python, I see updated length, for the moment, when python starts, and in this session, queue length is the same length, from starting application.

Is there any conditions, I missed? Or this is a bug of Django 1.6?

----- UPD1 -----:

```
logger.log( "Send from stock2 to stock1" )
for sms in SentSMS.objects.filter( sent_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours=2) ):
    try:
        logger.log( u"Transmitting sms: " + unicode( sms.phone ) + " with text \"" + unicode( sms.text ) + "\" and date " + unicode( datetime.datetime.now() ) )
        new_sms = SendSMS( phone = sms.phone, text = sms.text, free = sms.free, send_date = datetime.datetime.now(), price = sms.price, subscription = sms.subscription, priority = sms.priority )
        new_sms.save()
        sms.delete()
    except:
        logger.log( "Error with transmitting sms", level=Logger.WARNING )
        logger.print_exception()
logger.log( "Sleep one hour" )
time.sleep(3600*2)
```

---- UPD2 -----
Solved. It's bug of mysql. Table was recreated, and all goes to normal.

Comment: Can you add the code of that `"job"`?

Comment: Which database are you using, how are you managing transactions, and which commit mode are you running in. Your question reminds me of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data/7794220#7794220), but it's not quite the same because you're running Django 1.6.

Comment: Db is mysql with no transaction support

Comment: Where do you query for the count?

Comment: In python shell, serverside

Comment: Maybe you should show that code too...

Comment: Problem solved. It's a bug of mysql. Table was recreated, and all goes to normal. Thanks