# Django Cache (Redis) auto refresh when data is changed

Tags: python, django, postgresql, caching, redis

Is there any way to notify django to refresh the cache if there were any changes made on the database related to the cache data ? I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data), there is no latest answer and the django version mentioned was 1.6. I looked into the cache [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/) and haven't found anything that directly relates to the question.

My question is what if I cache a result of a database query and there are new records added in between the timeout for the cache

```
from django.core.cache import cache

results = MyModel.objects.all() # 4 count
cache.set('results', results ) # Cached for 5 mins

# Mean while records have been added to MyModel table

results = MyModel.objects.all() # 6 count
cache.get('results') # 4 count and would not be updated for 5 mins
```

Is there any way to check if there has been any addition to the database and the cache refresh whenever there has been addition or deletion of records from the database ?

I have close to 10 tables where this might be important. Where whenever a records has been changed, the cache has to be updated.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Project Stack:

```
Django: 1.9
Python: 3.5
Redis: 2.8 (Cache Database)
Postgres: 9.5 (Main Database)
```

Comment: I am running into similar issue but slightly different case. In my cache I am caching the result of some API to other application. So, wanted to know if there is a way to refresh the cache in background by doing the API call again instead of clearing the cache on update API call and load it again on get.

Comment: if i understand the question correcty https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops solves that problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So after an Year, this is what I have came up with

We can register custom post_save register to the models in the app.py for each app where you want to update your cache or add the post_save listener for all the models while the project is initializing.

These two post's helped to come up with receiver function which will clear the cache for the redis key.

In my application I used "{}-{}-{}".format(slug, model_name, username) to as key to my redis key and I will delete this key every time the model data for that user is changed.

Here are the post I found helpful:
[Blog](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html)