# Django command not noticing newly added data

Tags: django, orm

I'm running from the interactive shell (via ./manage.py shell_plus)

```
c = MyModel.objects.count()
while True
    assert MyModel.objects.count() == c
    sleep(1)
```

and then I go to the admin and add a new MyModel object. I would assume the assertion will fail, but it keeps getting the old count (not noticing the new record).

Do you know what is causing this? 
My first suspect is the cache system, but I don't know how to test it.
Do you know how to overcome this and allow the queries to notice the new records?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with transactions. You probably want to set your script to commit manually after each call to `process_records`.

See the [transaction docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/transactions/).

Comment: my endless script doesn't have problems writing data, it has problems noticing new data.
I'll update the question to show a simplified case

Comment: hmm appears you are right and it is related to transactions.  I found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886909/how-to-disable-django-query-cache and the transaction.commit() trick works for me. After I ran commit suddenly the reads return the new data. I thought transactions.commit affect writing to db, not reading... weird.

Comment: @Iftah: read up on transaction isolation: a transaction needs to be able to stand alone, so while it's open it doesn't see any data written by other transactions.