# Changes in DB data not reflecting in the Django queryset in a continuously looping script 

Tags: django, transactions, django-queryset, django-caching

I am using Django's ORM to get newly added entries from a Db and pass them to a Messaging queue. I am doing this in an infinite while loop , The PROBLEM in every loop iteration  I am getting the same queryset even when I have added/deleted/edited entries when this script is running,

The code goes like this :

```
while True :
    sleep(10 seconds)
    # Below is the problem line, I get the same query-set every time in new_objects
    # even when I have added/deleted/edited entries while this daemon is running.
    new_objects = Model.objects.filter(some condition)

    # Process new_objects and send them to MQ
    .
    . and so on
```

What should I do to reflect the latest data in each iteration ?

Comment: Duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886909/how-to-disable-django-query-cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with caching. This is to do with transactions.

A continuously-running script by default runs within a single transaction, and so will never see changes outside that transaction. You'll need to start a new transaction manually on every iteration - see [the transaction documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transaction-management-in-views) on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a ton Daniel, "A continuously-running script by default runs within a single transaction" this exactly was the problem. All I had to do was manually commit the transaction in each iteration and the changes started showing up.