# Django matching query does not exist after object save in Celery task

Tags: python, mysql, django, celery, django-celery

I have the following code:

```
@task()
def handle_upload(title, temp_file, user_id):
    .
    .
    .
    photo.save()
    #if i insert here "photo2 = Photo.objects.get(pk=photo.pk)" it works, including the         view function
    return photo.pk

#view function
def upload_status(request):
    task_id = request.POST['task_id']

    async_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
    photo_id = async_result.get()
    if async_result.successful(): 
        photo = Photo.objects.get(pk=photo_id)
```

I use an ajax request to check for the uploaded file but after the celery task finishes i get a Photo matching query does not exist. The photo pk does exist and gets returned. If i query the database manually it works. Is this some sort of database lag? How can I fix it?
I'm using Django 1.4 and Celery 3.0

Comment: How does your transaction settings look like?

Comment: I've left most settings on default. The only thing i've changed is CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 3600
as it would hang waiting for the task even after completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can confirm if it is a lag issue by adding a delay to your django view to wait after the task has successfully finished for a a few seconds. If that resolves the problem you might want to wrap the handle_upload in a transaction to block until the db has completely confirmed it has finished before returning.

Beside Django, DB too has its own caches. When django invokes the queryset, it gets stale data either from its own caches (unlikely unless you were reusing querysets, which I didn't see in the portion of the code you posted) or the DB is caching results for the same Django connection.

For example if you were to invoke post processing after the celery task has finished in a completely new django request/view you would probably see the new changes in DB just fine. However, since your view was blocked while the task was executing (which defeats the purpose of celery btw) internally django only keeps the snapshot of the DB at the time the view was entered. Therefore your get fails and you confirmed this behavior directly when simply entering the django shell.

You can fix this like you already did by either:

- invoking transactional management which will refresh the snapshot
- changing on your DB endpoint caching and autocommit policies
- have celery make a callback to django (web request) once it is done to finalize processing (which is likely what you want to do anyway because blocking django defeats the purpose)

Comment: I've added a 5 second delay before querying the database in the view but i get the same error. I now have no idea what is happening. I should mention that it did work on Celery 2.5 and Django 1.3.

Comment: I've launched in parallel with the task a django python shell and it wouldn't get the object no matter how much i waited. After i closed the shell and opened a new one i retrieved the object without any problems. The object shows in django admin right after the task is finished. Is the database cached or something?

Comment: Yes, in the view function, Django has a snapshot of the DB state and even if the DB changed, won't see it until the local transaction is finished. See comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886909/how-to-disable-django-query-cache for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added
    from django.db import transaction
    transaction.enter_transaction_management()
    transaction.commit()
to my view function and now it works.
I still don't understand why this happens. In the documentation it says querysets are cached if used more than once. I cannot however link that to my situation where in the view function I have only one query.

Comment: I decided not to mess around with transactions as it seems as a dirty hack to me so I've split the problem into two views. One for checking if the task has finished and to return the result and one for specific processing.
Although it doesn't seem best practice, I'm trying to make a console where I can see whether or not the photo has finished processing in real time using ajax. That is why I'm making the request hang until the task is finished. The other way is to ping the view once every 1-2 seconds and check for task.state. Which one do you think is best?

Comment: This is really a separate design question but why don't you split it into two separate calls? An Ajax call which blocks until the task is successful and immediately returns just "ready". Then your JS can issue another call to fetch the result? If you need this to scale up this approach won't work and you should consider a comet based (long polling) notifier. For more specifics its best you ask another question.