# Django 1.5 Admin - Object matching query does not exist - intermittent

Tags: python, django, django-models, pagination, django-admin

**Python 2.7.3
Django Version is 1.5**

I am using the standard Django Admin DefaultModelAdmin for adding and changing objects.

**Problem**

When I add an object using Django Admin Add View - about one in every ten times - I get this error:

```
Object matching query does not exist> Lookup parameters were {'objectid_exact':234}
```

Instead, Django should just return to the Paginated List View where all objects can be seen - but it seems cannot find the newly created object.

Note - I have DEBUG enabled here - otherwise I see a standard error 500 page.
The line of code it complains about is on my models.py class:
From models.py:

```
return "MyObject: %s: %s (by: %s)" % (self.pk, self.title, self.namelc)
```

The thing is, if I refresh the Django Admin the object has been added and there are no problems with it.

I did some research around this and found some articles and tried out recommendations - but they made no difference - for example:

1. [Django matching query does not exist after object save in Celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539152/django-matching-query-does-not-exist-after-object-save-in-celery-task)

Finally - I added this line of code to the end of the svae_model() method and it solved the problem:

```
my_list = list(models.MyObject.objects.all())
```

I am not sure why this solves the issue - it forces Django to re-evaluate the QuerySet as per these articles:

1. [Django lazy QuerySet and pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548744/django-lazy-queryset-and-pagination)
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/

There is no performance impact and so far, I have not seen the issue again.

I do no fully understand why this solves the issue so I would be grateful for any insights as to:

1. Why this work around seems to solve the issue?
2. Any insights as to the cause of the issue in the first place?

I am using @transaction.commit_on_success in the method that adds the item to DB - but as I said I think the issue is when Django tries to display the paginated List screen - it cannot find the newly created object.

Thanks in advance for any help - much appreciated!

Comment: This is by definition the correct behavior: you cannot rely on an asynchronous task to be completed in your main process. So make it synchronous (i.e. don't use `delay()`).

Comment: thank you Stan, appreciate the response, but I am not using delay() so the process is synchronous already, any other ideas?

Comment: Need more code to figure out.