# django flush query caches

Tags: django, caching

I have 2 instances of django application.
One is frontend - a normal wsgi app.
Another is backend - a twisted daemon running with ./manage.py rundaemon.
They share django settigns and models.

Now, when one of them has a query, it got cached.
And when another updates database - the cache will not be flushed.
That's obviously because they have no clue about another instance accessing the same database.

Is there a way to disable caching, or flush it manually and force query to be reexecuted?

(I guess the admin app does flush query caches somehow)

Comment: You should try to commit the transaction manually. See similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346124/how-do-i-force-django-to-ignore-any-caches-and-reload-data and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886909/how-to-disable-django-query-cache. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it worked for me when I faced the same problem.

```
import django
django.db.connection.close()
```

The connection will automatically get reopened the next time it is needed.