# Python variable scope and lazy querysets

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm using the Django and its out-of-the-box ORM. If there are some module level variables, are they only evaluated when the app starts? Or are they also evaluated on every request if it's modified in a view? An example:

```
from news.models import News

# Module level variables
draft_news = News.objects.filter(status='draft') 
live_news = News.objects.filter(status='prod')

def view(request):
    # outputs 10 an 10, respectively.
    print 'There are %d news objects and %d live objects. Adding a draft article' % (draft_news.count(), live_news.count()) 

    n = News(
        content='This is test content',
        status='draft',
        slug='this-is-a-test3',
        pubdatetime=datetime.now(),
    )
    n.save()

    print '...done. There are %d draft news objects.' % draft_news.count() # 11 objects
    print 'Changing status to live...'

    n.status='prod'
    n.save()

    print 'There are now %d live objects.' % live_news.count() # 11 objects
```

Since querysets are lazy, does it matter if they are in a module level or view level? I originally tested the above code in a management command.

Let's assume that refactoring is not an option.

Additional information: I have several app servers (uWSGI) sharing the same database. It seems like the module level variables are only changed when I restart the uWSGI processes on all of them. In other words, the new News object returns a 404 when using get_object_or_404 in a view.

Comment: Django or something like SQLAlchemy? might be helpful if we boil down to a specific ORM.

Comment: @CppLearner django. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter if they are in a module level or view level.

The declaration itself doesn't fire a db request. Only when you ask for concrete result (such as count or start iterating) an actual db hit does happen.

It is advisable to keep them on a view level to keep global namespace clean.

**Update:**
The problem with `.count()` giving outdated results is more connected with django db query [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) rather than laziness. Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886909/how-to-disable-django-query-cache) page for workarounds.

Comment: This was my initial impression. Querysets are lazy. But I added some additional information that contributes to my confusion.

Comment: I think it would better suited as another SO question entirely. You answered my question here and confirmed my intuition.