# Django: removed object causes IndexError

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am a bit confused and I need some help.

I am displaying my objects using ModelFormset, then I am dynamically removing them using Ajax and then saving all of the objects again also using Ajax call. Everything is dynamic and the page is not reloaded at any time.

The problem is that when Django tries to save the whole formset using Ajax alfter an object or two has been deleted, it looks for the deleted object(s) and raises an `IndexError: list index out of range`, because the object(s) isn't at the queryset anymore.

This is how I am displaying and saving the formsets (simplified version - I think this is where the error comes from):

```
def App(request, slug):
    TopicFormSet = modelformset_factory(Topic, form=TopicForm, extra=0, fields=('name',), can_delete=True)
    SummaryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Summary, form=SummaryForm, extra=0, fields=('content',), can_delete=True)
    tquery = user.topic_set.all().order_by('date')
    squery = user.summary_set.all().order_by('date')
    # saving formsets:
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        # the following two lines is where the error comes from:
        t_formset = TopicFormSet(request.POST) # formset instance
        s_formset = SummaryFormSet(request.POST) # formset instance
        s_formset.save()
        t_formset.save()
    return render (blah...)
```

This is how I am removing objects (this is a different view):

```
def Remove_topic(request, slug, id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=id)
    summary = Summary.objects.get(topic = topic) # foreign key relatonship

    topic.delete()
    summary.delete()

    # Ajax stuff....
    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse('blah..')
```

I have tried placing `queryset = tquery` and `queryset = squery` when instantiating `t_formset` and `s_formset`, but it didn't help. What should I do ? I am using Postgres db if that's useful.

The error:

```
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eimantas/Desktop/Projects/Lynx/lynx/views.py", line 122, in App
    t_formset = TopicFormSet(request.POST, queryset = tquery)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 441, in __init__
    super(BaseModelFormSet, self).__init__(**defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 56, in __init__
    self._construct_forms()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 124, in _construct_forms
    self.forms.append(self._construct_form(i))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 468, in _construct_form
    kwargs['instance'] = self.get_queryset()[i]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    return self._result_cache[k]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: could you enclose the `delete` process into the transaction, like suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4739960/771848)?

Comment: I am not sure if this is wat you meant, but I added two lines `transaction.enter_transaction_management()` and `transaction.commit()
` righ after the `topic.delete()` and `summary.delete()` lines, but unfortunately I am getting the same error.I also did the same thing before initiating the formsets but the error is the same.

Comment: You might also need to change the order of the delete - delete the topic after summary.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help either. I tried to leave only `summary.delete()`, but then the queryset can not find the deleted `Summary` as I thought. I somehow need to remove the deleted objects from the queryset if it's possible...

Comment: P.S. I found out that this is not the case - I forgot to mention that I am using Postgres. The problem still exists though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In G+ group I was adviced that technically it is possible to reset or "reload" the Queryset, but it would be very difficult to maintain "at all levels" and probably would give no benefit. I was adviced to use iteration and check if each object has been saved successfully when saving the formset forms (I would have to overwrite `form = TopicForm`'s and `form = SummaryForm`'s `save()` method.)

I decided not to use formsets at all, but to list and save each object individually, it will be better for me and my app's business logic.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case of a cascaded delete that is already deleting the summary object:

> When an object referenced by a ForeignKey is deleted, Django by
>   default emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE
>   and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The error traceback points me exactly to the line which is instantiation of Topic formset: `t_formset = TopicFormSet(request.POST, queryset = tquery)` (`Summary` object has foreign key to the `Topic`), so I think this is not the prolem. I have also tried to remove `summary.delete()` line but unfortunately it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with second view and Ajax calls. I think that You have messed up [management form's fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform). Like `initial_form_count`, `total_form_count` or something similar.

Another important point. Do not save formset before checking if it is valid:

```
t_formset = TopicFormSet(request.POST)
if t_formset.is_valid():
    t_formset.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have answered my own question though.