# Django Mysql querying in loop but getting same output

Tags: mysql, django, loops, caching, django-models

This below code in Django is printing same results all the time. Even if there are more rows in the mysql DB. Please Help.

```
    while True:
        print Event.objects.last().id
        time.sleep(5)
```

====edit====
There was something important I missed. The above is giving proper results but below one is not. I am using slave db here to read. But question still remains the same. Does this mean that there is some slave db configuration that is creating problem?

```
    while True:
        print Event.objects.using("read").last().id
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I think django caches the queryset in request thread. Further execution of the same will return the same value.

Comment: Yes it seems django is caching the query but what should I do. connection.close() and transaction.commit() also did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok to solve this you can look into.

[How to disable Django query cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886909/how-to-disable-django-query-cache)

Overall. The method enter_transaction_management no longer is there in django 1.1

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.enter_transaction_management()
transaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It because Django is caching the query: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets

Comment: Yes it seems django is caching the query but what should I do. connection.close() and transaction.commit() also did not help.